# How to create div to looks like this rectangle. With this form

Tags: html, css

This is div, who want to create. With these angles 2 x 2, but i don't know how to get only 2 x 2 from them, not all four. I need to create only form, without content and colors.

Comment: what are you talking about..which div.. 'don't know how to get only 2 x 2 from them, not all four'...well 2x2 is four..so you want to get 2x2 but not four...

Comment: I want to style 2 angles сeparately from other 2 angles

Answer (score 2):

Corners can only be rounded. Like the top right and bottom left. The other 2 corners cannot be done using html/css only. You'd need SVG or something similar.

Here's how you could get close...

```css
div{
background:black;
border-top-left-radius:30px;
border-bottom-right-radius:30px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
border-top-right-radius:10px;

width:100px;
height:80px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u, but i can create this, but can't complete it.

Comment: What do you mean by complete it? It's all you've asked... If we forget about the part we cannot do in HTML/css

Comment: to looks like image

Comment: you said "without colors and content" so my answer fits perfectly with your request... Be MORE SPECIFIC if I've missed something, just state what I missed, help me help you...

Comment: Dude top left and bottom right angles are Straight lines, in your example they aren't.

Comment: Corners can only be rounded, they cannot be straight lines like you wish. At least not with plain html/css. Are you willing to use another tehcno?

Comment: "I want to style 2 angles сeparately from other 2 angles" I have well shown you how to do this... Please stick to your original question.

Comment: maybe use hexagon instead of rectangle:)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I didn't understand your question. Which part of the image you want to implement. Here is close approximation in pure css. Play with it may be you will get what you want.

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:75px;
  border-radius:0px 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,transparent,transparent 10%,rgba(0,0,0,40%) 10%, rgba(0,0,0,40%) 90%,transparent 90%,transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Only frame i want

Comment: just elaborate a little bit..what do you mean by frame in image?

Comment: I just used my all knowledge to create that.. and now the search continue

Comment: You can use a few more gradient and use background-size to draw borders, Eventually, box-shadow can help for the rounded corners: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jLWqQe (you are welcome) But this is obviously an SVG job ;)